# VirtualHost AWS Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, amazon-aws, apache

Olá grande ninjas do linux.

Estou trabalhando no ec2 ubuntu da AWS, e to precisando criar um subdomínio.
Vi alguns tutoriais mas nenhum funcionou.

Eu criei um arquivo em:

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/

chamado de admin.conf. No arquivo eu coloquei:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerAdmin teste@site.com.br
    ServerName subdominio.site.com.br
    ServerAlias www.subdominio.site.com.br
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

No 000-default.conf está:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerAdmin teste@site.com.br
    ServerName site.com.br
    ServerAlias www.site.com.br
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

O site está abrindo normal, porém o subdominio não está abrindo. Diz: "Não é possível acessar esse site. Não foi possível encontrar o endereço IP do servidor"

Poderiam me ajudar? Deveras grato!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar a entrada no DNS para o subdomínio.

O conceito de subdomínio determina que você associe um endereço no caso de um registro do tipo A ou o nome do domínio raiz, ou outro qualquer, se o registro for do tipo *CNAME*.

Caso esteja usando *registro.br* crie uma entrada do tipo *CNAME* com o nome do seu subdomínio e o endereço coloque a raiz do seu domínio.

Comment: Fala aí, Henrique! Quando a pergunta não está clara o suficiente, o ideal é solicitar detalhes via comentário na pergunta, para então formular uma resposta. Assim que tiver reputação suficiente vai poder comentar em qualquer lugar. O máximo que pode fazer é especificar os casos na sua resposta (veja a [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/363521/revisions) que fiz). Caso não esteja de acordo com seu objetivo, você também pode reverter a edição. ;)